# String case reverse function in C++

Tags: c++, strings, c++11

This reverses the case of a character in a string (a string being an array of characters). How does it look? Anything I can improve on? Let's get critical here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//
// return a new string
//
std::string camel_case_rev(const std::string &word)
{
        std::string ret = "";

        for(unsigned i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
                if(word[i] <= 'Z' && word[i] >= 'A') {
                        ret += tolower(word[i]);
                }
                else if(word[i] <= 'z' && word[i] >= 'a') {
                        ret += toupper(word[i]);
                }
                else {
                        ret += word[i];
                }
        }
        return ret;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        if(argc < 2) {
                std::cerr << "USAGE: " << argv[0] << " " << "<string>\n";
                return 1;
        }

        std::string a = camel_case_rev(argv[1]);

        std::cout << a << "\n";

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: My C is rusted so I'm not going to post an answer. In the asciitable the difference between upper and lower characters is 1 bit. You could just flip the 6th bit with a xor. A = 1000001, a = 1100001

Comment: @the_lotus could you show me how to do that?

Comment: Like I said, my C is rusty. Might be something like this: if( (word[i] <= 'Z' && word[i] >= 'A') || (word[i] <= 'z' && word[i] >= 'a')) ret += word[i] ^ 0x20;  This assume that the string is encoded in ASCII

Comment: @the_lotus this has worked perfectly and it is my favorite improvement. If you choose to submit an answer, be sure that I will accept it.

Answer (score 19):

This seems like a perfect opportunity to leverage the standard library. I would make a function to toggle a single character and then use `std::transform` on top of that. Not only is it more consise, it will be more performant (you should use `reserve` to preallocate the resulting string -- otherwise the string may allocate over and over again).

```
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int toggle_case(int chr) {
    return std::islower(chr) ? std::toupper(chr) : std::tolower(chr);
}

std::string toggle_case(std::string str) {
    std::transform(std::begin(str), std::end(str), std::begin(str), toggle_case);
    return str;
}
```

Note that standard `islower` and `isupper` were used instead of comparison against character literals. Not only is it more compact and clearer, C++ does not guarantee that 'A', 'B', ..., 'Z' are contiguous.

Also, since you're (presumably) including the C++ version of `ctype.h`, `cctype`, you should be using `std::toupper` and `std::tolower`. C++ versions of C headers are allowed to place symbols in the global namespace, but they're only required to place them in `std`. There's no existing compiler I know of that doesn't also place them in the global namespace, but it can never hurt to strive for portabiltiy, especially when it's easy.

```
return std::islower(chr) ? std::toupper(chr) : std::tolower(chr);
```

This might look a little weird, but `std::tolower` and `std::toupper` are guaranteed to have no effect if no opposite-cased character exists for the input. In other words, `std::tolower(c)` is guaranteed to have no effect unless `std::toupper(c)` is true. To me, this makes sense and this short-cutted logic seems fairly natural. I could see this being rather weird to read though, so it might be better as a more explicit conditional chain.

I should also mention that the code makes an implicit copy of the string via the parameter. If you wanted to make the copy more explicit, you could, but that would actually be potentially hampering performance since it would disable movement into the parameter. In short, with the implicit copy, there's a potential that a copy will not actually happen. With an explicit copy, a copy will always happen.

Comment: You suggestion kinda screams for a lambda :)

Comment: @CodeClown Yeah, I should have at least mentioned the lambda option. It seems feasible though that you might want the per-character toggle function as an accessible thing.

Comment: Why did you use `int` instead of `char`?

Comment: @Paul the arg to isupper, islower is an int, you could also use unsigned char without any compiler warnings.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to default initialize a `std::string`.

```
std::string ret = "";
```

Has the equivalent result too:

```
std::string ret;
```

The `string` type has a constructor that creates an empty string automatically. It is OK though if you think the code looks clearer with the `= "";`.

To be exact:

```
std::string ret = "";  // Calls another constructor:       std::string::string(char const* s);
                       // Does what you expect; creates an empty string by copying the C-String
std::string ret;       // Calls the default constructor:   std::string::string()
                       // Does what you expect; creates an empty string.
```

---

`tolower` and `toupper` are declared in the [`<cctype>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/) header, so you should include it to make dependencies explicit. Currently, you are relying on the "residual" include from `<string>`.

Also, since they belong to the namespace `std`, you should instead use `std::tolower` and `std::toupper`.

---

`std::size_t` would be a more adequate type for the loop counter in the `for` that is compared to  `word.size()`. [`std::string::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) returns a `string::size_type` object, but that is just a typedef to `size_t`, so it is OK to use the shorter one in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

With C++11, you should use a [range-based `for`-loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), which uses iterators:

```
for (auto const& iter : word) {
    if (iter <= 'Z' && iter >= 'A') {
        ret += tolower(iter);
    }
    else if (iter <= 'z' && iter >= 'a') {
        ret += toupper(iter);
    }
    else {
        ret += iter;
    }
}
```

This helps avoid bounds-checking or possible mismatched loop counter types.  Also, making the iterator `const&` will prevent `word` from being modified and avoid copies on this read-only data.

Comment: The difference between `const auto &el` and `auto const &el` is nothing?

Comment: @true: I don't believe there is a difference.

Comment: You sure? e.g. in `const char* const` every const has its meaning.

Comment: @CodeClown: It works with my small tests, and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176104/c11-range-based-loop-get-item-by-value-or-reference-to-const) says the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If the string is ASCII endoded, you can flip the 6th bit since it represend the case for a letter.

Ex: A = 1000001, a = 1100001

Haven't used C in a while but here's what it could look like

```
if( (word[i] <= 'Z' && word[i] >= 'A') || (word[i] <= 'z' && word[i] >= 'a') )
    ret += word[i] ^ 0x20;
```